Why does neovim not see my python script in Command-Line mode?
For my goals I wrote two simple scripts - 1 bash script and 1 python script. Below I attached them.
Bash:
#!/bin/bash

cat $1 | xclip -selection clipboard

Python:
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
import os

PATH = '/home/gipakrot/sql/sql_ex/solutions'

files = os.listdir(PATH)

current_file = sys.argv[1]

if current_file in files:
    version = 1
    task = current_file[2: current_file.find('.sql')]
    for file in files:
        if file.startswith(f'ex{task}_'):
            version += 1
    final_name = f'ex{task}_{version}.sql'

else:
    final_name = current_file

with open(current_file, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

with open(f'{PATH}/{final_name}', 'a') as f:
    for line in lines:
        f.write(line)

Also i made aliases for both of them:
alias movesql='mvsql.py'
alias copysql='copysql.sh'

I want to use them in neovim Command-Line mode.
When I am trying to use these scripts in neovim Command-Line mode:
:!copysql or :!movesql

I get these error:
:!copysql [Command Line]                                                                                                      
/bin/bash: line 1: copysql: command not found

shell returned 127

Can you help me to fix this problem? Don't see what I do wrong. In terminal both scripts (via aliases) works as expected.

. is not usually in $PATH. Put the scripts in a directory that's in $PATH or put the absolute pathname in the aliases.

This has nothing to do with neovim. You would have the same problem if you typed the alias at a normal shell prompt.

What experienced users do is create a directory like ~/bin and put their personal scripts in there. Then add that directory to $PATH in your .profile.

@Barmar won't work from Vim because :! will run a non-interactive shell and not look at .profile unless you tweak shellcmdflag which in turn creates problems of its own.

@Friedrich PATH is normally exported so it will be inherited by all shells during the login session. So you only need to set it in .profile.

@Barmar yep, PATH will work, the aliases won't. OP had the aliases in their question and I missed that your proposal works without them.

Yeah, forgot about that. You should just execute the python and shell scripts directly, without going through the aliases. If you don't want to have to type the .py and .sh extensions, you can leave them out of the script filenames.

In any case, none of this about programming. Questions about using Unix interactively belong in [unix.se].

I dont have any problems when I type them in a normal shell prompt, they work expectedly.
But thank you both! I put both scripts in ~/.local/bin without extensions and under the names I want them to use, and they work in shell and in neovim.

To refine your solution, you can put your scripts anywhere, with any names. Then create symlinks without extensions in a directory in PATH.

This is because the shell provided via the :! interface in neovim is not an interactive shell. We can verify this via :!echo $-. The resulting string of characters does not include i. As a result, aliases (and functions) will not be loaded in. A good alternative for you would to be to symlink these two scripts into ~/.local/bin, which is a common spot for user scripts. Depending on what distribution you're on, this directory may or may not be in your PATH environment variable, so check to make sure, and add it in your .bashrc or other init script if not. Note that the exact name of the symlink is what you will call to execute the script, so consider ln -s mvsql.py ~/.local/bin/mvsql (or something even shorter if you're going to be using it a lot) so you don't have to include the .py when calling it.
